# ошибка компиляции при использовании bind2nd

Tags: c++, c++17

Начал переносить свой проект на /std:C++17 и возникла ошибка с bind2nd, вот код:

```
void GlobalFeelTouch::feel_touch_update(Fvector& P, float R)
{
    //we ignore P and R arguments, we need just delete evaled denied objects...
    xr_vector<Feel::Touch::DenyTouch>::iterator new_end = 
        std::remove_if(feel_touch_disable.begin(), feel_touch_disable.end(), 
            std::bind2nd(delete_predicate_by_time(), Device.dwTimeGlobal)); //Ошибка тут
    feel_touch_disable.erase(new_end, feel_touch_disable.end());
}

bool GlobalFeelTouch::is_object_denied(CObject const * O)
{
    /*Fvector temp_vector;
    feel_touch_update(temp_vector, 0.f);*/
    if (std::find_if(feel_touch_disable.begin(), feel_touch_disable.end(),
        std::bind2nd(objects_ptrs_equal(), O)) == feel_touch_disable.end()) //Ошибка тут
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Требуется замена bind2nd, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: С ответами согласен :) замечу только, что во второй функции вместо кода вида `if (x ==y) return false; else return true;` проще и короче записать `return x != y;`   Ну а за наименование переменной O отдельный минусик, начинаешь вглядываться в условие и думать, почему там ноль...

Answer (score 3):

`std::bind1st` and `std::bind2nd` были удалены из С++17. `std::bind` остался, но им не стоит пользоваться (корявый интерфейс - его результат можно вызвать с лишними аргументами, и они просто отбрасываются).

Лучше всего использовать `std::bind_front` (C++20) или `std::bind_back` (C++23) или лямбду. (Для вашего случая подходят последние два.)

Но я бы на вашем месте переписал предикаты, чтобы они вызывались так: `delete_predicate_by_time(Device.dwTimeGlobal)`, и возвращали лямбду, захватывающую аргумент.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать лямбду или `std::bind`. На примере [отсюда](https://cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind2nd/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  int numbers[] = {10,-20,-30,40,-50};
  int cx1, cx2, cx3;
  cx1 = count_if ( numbers, numbers+5, bind2nd(less<int>(),0) );
  cx2 = count_if ( numbers, numbers+5, bind(less<int>(), placeholders::_1, 0) );
  cx3 = count_if ( numbers, numbers+5, [](int x){ return less<int>()(x,0);});
  cout << "There are " << cx1 << " (bind2nd) " << cx2 << " (bind) " << cx3 << " (lambda) negative elements.\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Результат:

```
There are 3 (bind2nd) 3 (bind) 3 (lambda) negative elements.
```

В `bind` `placeholders::_1` означает, какой параметр из переданных в возвращённый `bind`-ом объект окажется на месте соответствующего аргумента функции:

```
auto f1 = bind(less<int>(), placeholders::_1, 0);
f1(2); //less<int>()(2, 0)
auto f2 = bind(less<int>(), 0, placeholders::_1);
f2(2); //less<int>()(0, 2)
auto f3 = bind(less<int>(), placeholders::_2, placeholders::_1);
f3(2, 1); //less<int>()(1, 2)
```

Начиная с С++14 в лямбдах можно использовать `auto`:

```
[](auto x){ return less<int>()(x,0);}
```